# Itemscontrol display only first element of the collection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have `ItemControl`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasCollection}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>                    
                      <Canvas Width="{Binding CanvasSize}" Height="{Binding CanvasSize}" Background="RoyalBlue" />                       
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:VertexViewModel}">
                    <Thumb Width="11" Height="11">
                        <Thumb.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Ellipse Width="11" Height="11" Fill="{Binding Fill}" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Thumb.Template>
                    </Thumb>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And composite collection with currently one `ObservableCollection`:

```
private ObservableCollection<VertexViewModel> Points { get; set; }
public CompositeCollection CanvasCollection { get; set; }
```

While debugging, I see that collection contains two elements, as I accepted, but only first is displaying on Canvas. When I call `Refresh()` method in model, I see that binding working, but only for first element.

Adding Point to CompositeCollection:

```
Points = new ObservableCollection<VertexViewModel>();
        CanvasCollection = new CompositeCollection()
        {
            Points
        };
```

Comment: What happens if you write `ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"`?

Comment: Hmm, this way all works, but i don't understand, what's wrong with CompositeCollection.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use container for collectoin:

```
 CanvasCollection = new CompositeCollection
        {
            new CollectionContainer() {Collection = Points},
           Polygon,
        };
```